# Angular ngIf render not effect

Tags: angular

I use google+ api to get the user profile.

After I get the profile ,change my property to show my button.

I can get the profile and change my property.

However the page is not rendering.

Console doesn't have any error message.

If i don't use the google+ api ,it works.

.html

```
      <h3 *ngIf="showArray.showLoginButton">
        <a (click)="openMask()"></a>
      </h3>
      <h3 *ngIf="!showArray.showLoginButton">
        <a (click)="clickLogout()"></a>
      </h3>

  <div id="mask" *ngIf="showArray.showMask">       
      <button (click)="googleLogin()">        
        Sign Up with Google
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

component.ts

```
  showArray = {
    showMask: false,
    showLoginButton: false,
  };

openMask() {
    this.showArray.showMask = true;
  }

 googleLogin() {
   this.logStatus.onSignIn().subscribe(() => {
       this.showArray.showMask = false;
       this.showArray.showLoginButton = false;      
   });
 }
```

LogStatusService.ts

```
constructor() {
    this.googleInit();
}

googleInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id:
          'ID',
        cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email',
      });
    });
}

onSignIn(element?): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.auth2.signIn()).pipe(
      tap((googleUser: any) => {
        const token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN, token);        
      })
    );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Don't use Tap generate side effects besides Logging or Messaging, this makes it hard to debug, do all the Operations in you subscribe Method:

```js
   public showArray = {
    showMask: false,
    showLoginButton: false,
  };

 public googleLogin(): void {
   this.logStatus.onSignIn().subscribe((token:string) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', token);
       this.showArray.showMask = false;
       this.showArray.showLoginButton = false;      
   },
   error =>{
         console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
 }
```

Then use the error callback of the subscribe method to find out, what goes wrong while doing the request.

```js
public onSignIn(element?): Observable<string> {
    return from(this.auth2.signIn())
           .pipe(map(googleUser => googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token))
    );
}
```

After trying this you might get a usefull error, and you can edit your post.

Also, what do you mean with "If i don't use the google+ api ,it works" ?
Not initilitailizing it in the constructor at all or just not using the login method ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesnt have any error message.I mean that my `onSignIn()` method return `new Observable((subject)=>{subject.next();subject.complete();})` .